# How to scrape the following table in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I need to scrape in R the table at the bottom of the page of the following link:

https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/azo/autozone/pe-ratio

Comment: This article will provide you with information that should help you: https://rvest.tidyverse.org/articles/harvesting-the-web.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `rvest`

Web scraping part

```
library(rvest)
webpage <- read_html("https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/azo/autozone/pe-ratio")
html <- rvest::html_nodes(webpage, "thead+ thead th , #style-1 td")
results <- rvest::html_text(html)
```

Split the columns out, since `results` is just a list

```
Date <- results[seq(5, length(results), 4)]
`Stock Price` <- results[seq(6, length(results), 4)]
`TTM Net EPS` <- results[seq(7, length(results), 4)]
`PE Ratio` <- results[seq(8, length(results), 4)]
results <- data.frame(Date, `Stock Price`, `TTM Net EPS`, `PE Ratio`, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Have a look

```
head(results)
        Date Stock.Price TTM.Net.EPS PE.Ratio
1 2020-04-27     1060.52                16.25
2 2020-02-29     1032.51      $65.27    15.82
3 2019-11-30     1177.92      $64.37    18.30
4 2019-08-31     1101.69      $63.54    17.34
5 2019-05-31     1027.11      $55.97    18.35
6 2019-02-28      938.97      $53.40    17.58
```

Comment: It is an amazing idea. Thank you very much!